# What is the idea called when something has happened to you but you just don't know?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There is a word/idea that something has happened to you, but you just don't know that it already has occured.

```
Question
Have you ever been phished before?

Answer
1. Yes.
2. No, I have never been phished before.
3. I don't know.
```

In this case, say for number 2 (and for intents and purposes that the phishing is silent), you HAVE been phished, you just wouldn't have known it has happened to you. For you, you feel this is true but it may not be because you wouldn't know.

What is this idea called? Naive, Ignorance? I'm looking for an ideology word if one exists, like Occam's razor or even an expression.

Comment: ‘Blissful ignorance’ suits this situation.

Comment: I am not aware that I have been phished. I have no awareness of being phished.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

‘Blissful ignorance’ suits this situation.

> **Blissful ignorance:**
> a state in which you do not know about something unpleasant or worrying, so it does not make you unhappy.

[[**Macmillan dictionary**]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/blissful-ignorance)

Answer (score 0):

**Blithe ignorance**, means you might be aware of what has happened but you are ignorant of the significance and you treat it with little concern.